# "in most of the world" or "over most of the world"?

Tags: word-choice

I am comparing two S and F datasets against another one B at global scale.

Is it right to say:

> S was closer to B in most of the world than F.

or

> S was closer to B over most of the world than F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to keep the world part separate.  Either before the comparison, or after it, and possibly using the phrase "on a worldly scale".  Otherwise I would go with "in":

```
In most of the world, S was closer to B than F.
```

Answer (score -1):

"in most of the world" would be used in your case.

Comment: And why? Any explanations?

Comment: *Very loosely*, personally, I'd use "over" when talking about oceans, weather, natural phenomena, etc.; and "in" when talking about people.

Comment: A prime purpose of this site is to *educate* OPs so that they understand the reasons and *learn*, so that they know what to do on a similar future occasion. So please ***explain*** your answers.